# How to create a Checkpoint in UFT

Tags: hp-uft

Strange enough that I have to ask such a simple question.
I started automating with UFT and I suppose the correct way to check if for instance my login has worked is to add a checkpoint on the next page.
But how do I do that?

All info I get from google is on how to add an already existing checkpoint to may page. But I don't have any.

Here is how I go about automating:

- I add manually the relevant objects to the object repository
- I create parameters for  my action
- I create the code that does the steps on the page
- one action per page seems to be fine for me

But in the Object Repository of UFT 14.53, there is no button to add a Checkpoint.
A workaround for me would be to just add another Object and check it's existence and forget about checkpoints. Until I hopefully get an answer here, I will try to do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UFT there are typically two ways to verify that things are working as expected.

1. **Flow (implicit)** - In order to verify that progress in the application is successful (e.g. login) one usually just keeps working with the app, assuming that if the previous step failed, the objects needed for the next steps won't exist and the test will fail due to *ObjectNotFound* errors
2. **State (explicit)** - In order to see that objects have a specific state, checkpoints are usually used. Checkpoints are typically added during a record session, I'm not sure if there's a way to add them directly to the repository. An alternative to checkpoints, which works better with keyword driven testing (no recording), is to use the built in [`CheckProperty`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/15.0/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#Common_Methods_and_Properties/Common_Methods_and_Properties.html#CheckProperty) method.